# What can I do to bring my hierarchy back?

Tags: modeling

[image: Picture of the bar missing the hierarchy]

I have no idea what I did, but my hierarchy is gone. I'm trying to make a VR character, but I can't finish it without the hierarchy. It shows up if I open another project, but I don't want to start over. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have accidentally [closed that panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/207624/5705).  You can actually make any panel in your view an outliner by clicking on the button on the top-left corner of the panel.

To open it again as it was, simply click and drag from the top-right corner of the properties panel and drag down, then change the new panel you just created to an outliner.

[image]