# Lost the scene collection 'tab'

Tags: scene

All of a sudden (yeh I realise that it is my own doing) I have lost my scene collection panel (right of the 3d viewport) and cannot work out how to get it back even after searching the manual and doing a 'google' search. The 'situation' I am in seems to be saved with my project as some of my projects show the panel and others don't.
What have I done or more to the point how do I get it back? [image]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/index.html#editors  change area type back to outliner.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/207626/110840

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I now also see that shift F9 can also display 'outliner'. I also must have dragged the Properties panel up as when displayed the 'outliner' panel my Properties panel disappeared but I quickly fixed that. Still lots to learn for this newbie.

Comment: off topic, but that floating dock looks really neat :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jachym and thanks again for your patience and educating me in many aspects of Blender. (The low poly tires came from turbosquid - "give credit where credit is due")