# blender file screen got cut in half

Tags: modeling, workflow

My Blender file opens in this weird way, it's with this file, the only i can do with that top screen, is slide the side windows to it, but when i slide those back it creates this trippy stuff it only happens with this one file, what should i do about it?[image][image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/207626/110840  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165915/110840

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/how-can-i-reset-my-menus

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open new scene **File** → **New** → **General**
2. **File** → **Open** and in the file browser open side panel using gear icon in the right top corner:

[image]

3. Uncheck **Load UI**
4. Now choose the file and open it. The data should be loaded, keeping interface untouched.