# Help with GUI Blender - Outliner and Properties area disappeared

Tags: interface, tools

So I'm new to Blender, and I got stuck. I was trying the interface of the program, and my tool area on the right side by default just disappeared. I was reading about this in the documentation and on youtube and still don't know how to bring it back. Here is the screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/207626/110840 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165915/110840

Answer (score 0):

You can press  <kbd>N</kbd> to bring the tab back. I recommend looking into blender shortcuts before using it.

Comment: Thanks, but i kinda lost tools area. How can i create new window with tools, or objects that are in the scene.

Comment: there should be a little notch when you hover about the top left corner. If you drag that out you should have a new tab. After hover to the bottom right corner and do the same thing to get the second tab. You can learn how to change these tabs by watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mf3nDys01H0

Comment: Thanks a lot lad! That is exactly what i need, sorry for kinda stupid question and unaccurate question form

Comment: glad I could help :D